# Plot a shape on previous week's high in pinescript

Tags: plot, pine-script, pine-script-v5

Trying to plot a shape on the previous week's high, but having difficulty getting it to plot. Hope someone can help here

````
indicator("My script", overlay = true)


previousWeekHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on, gaps = barmerge.gaps_off)

isNewWeek = timeframe.change("W") 

anchor_point() =>
    float anchor = na   
    if isNewWeek 
        anchor := previousWeekHigh 
    anchor
anchorBar = anchor_point() 


plotshape(anchorBar, style=shape.xcross)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really use the `plotshape()` for this purpose as the position of the weekly high bar will be dynamic.

I would just use two `var` variables, one for the price and one for the "bars since" count. You don't even need the `security()` here.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

is_new_week = ta.change(time("W"))
bgcolor(is_new_week ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)

var label weekly_high_lbl = label.new(na, na, "Weekly\nHigh", yloc=yloc.abovebar, style=label.style_label_down, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)
var line weekly_high_line = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
var float weekly_high_price = na
var int weekly_high_barssince = 0

if (is_new_week)
    // Update the label and line first
    label.set_xy(weekly_high_lbl, bar_index - weekly_high_barssince, weekly_high_price)

    line.set_xy1(weekly_high_line, bar_index - weekly_high_barssince, weekly_high_price)
    line.set_xy2(weekly_high_line, bar_index, weekly_high_price)

    // Reset the variables
    weekly_high_price := high
    weekly_high_barssince := 0
else
    // Check for new high
    if (high >= weekly_high_price)
        weekly_high_price := high
        weekly_high_barssince := 1
    else
        weekly_high_barssince := weekly_high_barssince + 1  // Increase the counter
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! but the weekly high will be static as i'm only looking for the previous week's highs.. so at the start of the week - plotshape or label at previous week's high

Comment: just realised thats what your code does. thank you! any thoughts on how would I apply this to historical weekly highs as well?

Comment: You can use an array. Or if you don't need to store information and if you just want to mark the candle and price, you can use a simple `label` and `line` instead of the `var` ones. And, instead of updating the coordinates in that if check, just do `line.new()` and `label.new()`.